# How to use unpivot for multiple columns with constants/missing column?

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

I'm trying to use the UNPIVOT in order to avoid the old-fashioned way of multiple unions

The rationale for this is I'm collecting some data (lab test, result, unit, ...) I'd like to display in a appropriate way for reviewing them

Let's say, for example, my raw data looks like this:

```
ID, TESTA, RESULTA, UNITA, TESTB, RESULTB, UNITB, OTHER_UNITB
1,  'T1',  10,      1,     'T2',  2.5,          , 'kg',
2,  'T1',  15,      1,     'T2',  1.5,     1,         ,
3,  'T1',    ,       ,     'T2',  1,       1,
```

The following just works perfectly: for each ID, I retrieve 1 line per test with the corresponding result and unit:

```
select  id,
        property as test_code,
        decode(property, 'T1', 'Test 01', 'T2', 'Test 02', 'Unknown test') as test_name,
        result,
        unit
from    my_table
unpivot include nulls
        (
            (result, unit)
            for property in (
              (resulta, unita) as 'T1',
              (resultb, unitb) as 'T2'
            )
        )
;
```

However, things goes wrong when I try to retrieve the 'other unit' that is specific to the test 'T2' (keep in mind it's an example, I've got plenty of tests, almost 20)

I tried this:

```
select  id,
        property as test_code,
        decode(property, 'T1', 'Test 01', 'T2', 'Test 02', 'Unknown test') as test_name,
        result,
        unit,
        other_unit
from    my_table
unpivot include nulls
        (
            (result, unit, other_unit)
            for property in (
              (resulta, unita, null) as 'T1',
              (resultb, unitb, other_unitb) as 'T2'
            )
        )
;
```

It fails with message "Invalid identifier" for the 'null' statement I put in the unpivot.

I tried also to use a constant, in such way:

```
....
unpivot include nulls
        (
            (result, unit, other_unit)
            for property in (
              (resulta, unita, 0) as 'T1',
              (resultb, unitb, other_unitb) as 'T2'
            )
        )
;
```

And that fails too.

I'm stuck here and cannot figure out how to fix that without re-writting everything is a list of union statements - that I'd like to avoid at all cost because that's pretty complex to maintain:

```
select resulta as result,
       unita as unit,
       null as other_unit
from   my_table
union
select resultb as result,
       unitb as unit,
       other_unitbas other_unit
from   my_table
union
...
```

I also found a ugly solution:

```
select  id,
        property as test_code,
        decode(property, 'T1', 'Test 01', 'T2', 'Test 02', 'Unknown test') as test_name,
        result,
        unit,
        other_unit
from    (
            select  m.*,
                    null as null_item
            from    my_table m
        )

unpivot include nulls
        (
            (result, unit, other_unit)
            for property in (
              (resulta, unita, null_item) as 'T1',
              (resultb, unitb, other_unitb) as 'T2'
            )
        )
;
```

But honestly, I'm ashamed to do that!

Thanks by advance for any support

Comment: Why are you ashamed of the "ugly" solution? The additional column you generate is appropriately named and the query is clear what it does; there is nothing to be ashamed of, it isn't ugly and you should use it.

Comment: My main concern is I'll have to create as many "pseudo columns" as I need for constant values. 

That works, I was just wondering if there is a way to write the default values/null values inside the unpivot clause

Answer (score 0):

You can check syntax diagram for `unpivot clause`.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#CHDJBHHI

It clearly shows that only `column`s may appear in a list (not literals or expressions).
[image]

You may need to create as many constant columns in inline view as many **distinct** constant values you require.

As an alternative approach, you can use old-school method: cross join + decode.

```
select id,
       test_code,
       decode(test_code, 'T1', 'Test 01', 'T2', 'Test 02', 'Unknown test') as test_name,
       decode(test_code, 'T1', resulta, 'T2', resultb) result,
       decode(test_code, 'T1', unita, 'T2', unitb) unit,
       decode(test_code, 'T2', other_unitb) other_unit
  from my_table t,
       (select 'T' || level test_code from dual connect by level <= 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, at least that clarifies what cannot be done in my case !